# How to create a Slide-Out Navigation Panel in iOS where the side panel goes over the center panel?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiviewcontroller

I followed [this great tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32054/how-to-create-a-slide-out-navigation-like-facebook-and-path) by Tammy Coron. Everything is great, and I understand how it works, but what I want to achieve is a little different. I want the central view to be "static", so to speak, and the side panels to overlap this central view.
So I should change this part:

```
UIView *childView = [self getLeftView];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:childView];
 
[UIView animateWithDuration:SLIDE_TIMING delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                animations:^{
                    _centerViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width - PANEL_WIDTH, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
                }
                completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    if (finished) {
 
                        _centerViewController.leftButton.tag = 0;
                    }
                }];
```

to something else. But playing around with it for a while did not yield the desired result.
Does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
_centerViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width - PANEL_WIDTH, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
```

to this line

```
childView.frame = CGRectMake(PANEL_WIDTH, 0, childView.frame.size.width, childView.frame.size.height);
```

Also don't sendsubViewToBack, change this line

```
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:childView];
```

to this line

```
[self.view bringSubViewToFront:childView];
```

Comment: Hey, thanks :) I played yesterday with bringSubviewToFront but it didn't work -- the center view always "disappeared".
So I didn't clarify that this was for the left button so the answer is correct, but if anyone else sees this it should be childview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, ...)
Also, the actual problem was in the xib file for the leftpanel view -- there was an opaque image on the right and the view was not set to be transparent. When I finally figured it out, everything worked as expected.